# AngularJS - Looping through array is throwing Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code which I would like push the array data into a scope for showing pins on a map. It shows the first pin but doesn't do the others.

**When It's run i get the error: Error:** [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.0' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [markers.0] starting at [.0].

My code is:

```
$scope.markers = [];
    var pos = [
    {      
        lat: 51.918374,
        lng: 19.594210
    },
    {        
        lat: 51.018374,
        lng: 19.094210
    },
     {        
        lat: 52.518374,
        lng: 19.594210
    },
    {        
        lat: 52.018374,
        lng: 19.694210
    }];
    pos.forEach(function(value){
      $scope.markers.push({
         lat: value.lat,
         lng: value.lng,
         message: "aaaa",
         focus: false,
         draggable: false
        });
    });
```

Tried using the angular.forEach:

```
var pos = [
    {      
        lat: 51.918374,
        lng: 19.594210
    },
    {        
        lat: 51.018374,
        lng: 19.094210
    },
     {        
        lat: 52.518374,
        lng: 19.594210
    },
    {        
        lat: 52.018374,
        lng: 19.694210
    }];
    var log = [];
    angular.forEach(pos, function(value, key) {
      this.push({
         lat: value.lat,
         lng: value.lng,
         message: "aaaa",
         focus: false,
         draggable: false
        });
    }, log);
    console.log(log);
    $scope.markers = log;
```

HTML:

```
<leaflet layers="map" center="map.center" overlay="map.overlays" markers="markers" ng-if="map"></leaflet>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Looks fine, can you post a demo to reproduce the issue? Also, try using `map`, like `$scope.markers = post.map(...)`

Comment: You should use `angular.forEach` [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Comment: There's also angular.forEach, you should try that...

Comment: @tomepejo why should OP @tutchmedia use `angular.forEach`?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. I've tried angular and the same error... See above code

Comment: Could you post your HTML code please. I think it the error is from there

Comment: I believe `markers` should be an object, not an array

Comment: @tutchmedia, you have some error in you directive. Here is an [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tomepejo/10fogrqa/) where I used your code.

Comment: @tutchmedia, @dcodesmith is right. `markers` must be Object, not an Array.

Comment: Tried your changes and it's still giving me that error :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/marker), markers should be an object, not an array.

```
$scope.markers = {};
var pos = [{
    lat: 51.918374,
    lng: 19.594210
}, {
    lat: 51.018374,
    lng: 19.094210
}, {
    lat: 52.518374,
    lng: 19.594210
}, {
    lat: 52.018374,
    lng: 19.694210
}];

pos.forEach(function (value, index) {
    $scope.markers[index] = {
        lat: value.lat,
        lng: value.lng,
        message: "aaaa",
        focus: false,
        draggable: false
    };
});
```

Comment: No, it will be an object. Have you actually checked that it's an object? Why the downvote? If you don't want it, just leave it! @tomepejo.

Comment: Just tried your changes and it still gives me the same error :(

Comment: post a fiddle then. in any case, you should check the documentation thoroughly

Comment: Will it matter that i'm using Ionic too?

Comment: Hard to tell. Trying stripping out all ionic related code first, and just try and get `leaflet` to work first

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I fixed it in this way:

1. updating the angular-leaflet-directive version [angular-leaflet-directive source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/master/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js)
2. including angular-simple-logger into my project [angular-simple-logger source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/index.js)